# Problems with JavaFX (KeyEvent and Controller)

Tags: javafx

I'm a beginner and can't get any further. I created two FXML files in Scene Builder. If you click on a button there, a new window opens (works). However, the new title is not displayed in the new window. I want to test a method there and there is no output in the console. Can you help?

First Controller (First Window)

```
public class StartController {
    
    //private ViewPlayer viewplayer = new ViewPlayer();

    @FXML
    private Button playButton;

    @FXML
    void buttonTapped(ActionEvent event) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlloader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/playAnonym.fxml"));
        
        try {
            fxmlloader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Parent root = fxmlloader.getRoot();
        PlayAnonymController controller = fxmlloader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            try {
                controller.movePlayer(e);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

FXML for First Window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.StartController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="258.0" layoutY="25.0" text="Space Invaders" />
      <Button layoutX="258.0" layoutY="98.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Registrieren" />
      <Button layoutX="264.0" layoutY="145.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Anmelden" />
      <Button fx:id="playButton" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="260.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonTapped" text="Spielen ohne Anmeldung" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Second Controller

```
public class PlayAnonymController{
    

    @FXML
    private Rectangle PLAYER;
    
    @FXML
    private Label gamoverLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label scoreLabel;
    
    @FXML
    public void movePlayer(KeyEvent event) throws IOException{
        
// keyboard code for the pressed key
        KeyCode key = event.getCode(); 
 
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case LEFT:
            PLAYER.setTranslateX(-10);
             //System.out.println("Key Pressed: ");
               break;
            case RIGHT:
            PLAYER.setTranslateX(+10);
             //System.out.println("Key Pressed: ");
               break;
            
            }
 
    }

}
```

Second FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.PlayAnonymController">
   <top>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <left>
            <Label fx:id="scoreLabel" text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </left>
         <center>
            <Label fx:id="gamoverLabel" text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Label text="Move: Pfeiltaste links / recht. Schießen Space." BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Rectangle fx:id="PLAYER" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#000911" height="5.0" layoutX="280.0" layoutY="305.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="40.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Why does your second controller extend `Application`? You are already setting the title of the second stage in the event handler method `buttonTapped()` in the `StartController`, which should work fine. It’s not really clear what you’re trying to do.

Comment: In the PlayAnonymController is a Rectangle. In the movePlayer method I want to move the rectangle with keyboard (LEFT). For testing I want an output in the console. It does not work. @James_D

Comment: The handler method in the second controller is not registered with any node, so it never gets invoked. But none of this explains why you made the second controller a subclass of `Application`. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Subclassing Application was just a try. Will be deleted. ;-) thanks. A game is to take place later in PlayAnonymController. Should I set up a completely new scene here?

Comment: A try *to do what*? I don’t understand what you’re asking. You are already setting up a completely new scene. If the only problem is that your `movePlayer()` method is not getting called, then that’s for the reason I said earlier: that event handler is not registered with anything.

Comment: Call the method like this -> scene.setOnKeyPressed( e -> movePlayer(e) )? @James_D

Comment: You either need a reference to the scene in the controller, which is difficult, or a reference to the controller at the place you create the scene. I would do the latter, e.g. `PlayAnonymController controller = fxmlloader.getController();` and then `scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> controller.movePlayer(e));` (or, more succinctly, `scene.setOnKeyPressed(controller::movePlayer));`). Just put that code right after loading the fxml and creating the scene.

Comment: Your new version of `PlayAnonymController` won't compile (the `@Override` annotation is on a method which does not override anything). I do not understand what you are trying to do with the `start(...)` method in that class. What is the point of that method? It will not be invoked from anywhere, and the code you have there simply replicates the things you are already doing in the `buttonTapped()` method in the first controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your `PlayAnonymController` has a `start()` method. That method does not appear to be called anywhere in your code, will not compile (because of the incorrect `@Override` annotation), and the code there simply replicates what you are already doing in the `buttonTapped()` method in `StartController`. Your `PlayAnonymController` should look like this:

```
public class PlayAnonymController{
    

    @FXML
    private Rectangle player;
    
    @FXML
    private Label gamoverLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label scoreLabel;
    
    @FXML
    public void movePlayer(KeyEvent event) throws IOException{
        
        KeyCode key = event.getCode();  // keyboard code for the pressed key
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + key);  // for testing
 
    }

}
```

You probably want to register the key event handler on the scene; to do that you need to register the handler at the point in the code where you have a reference to the scene, which is in the `buttonTapped()` method. All you need to do is get a reference to the controller in order to do that:

```
public class StartController {
    
    //private ViewPlayer viewplayer = new ViewPlayer();

    @FXML
    private Button playButton;

    @FXML
    void buttonTapped(ActionEvent event) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlloader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/playAnonym.fxml"));
        
        try {
            fxmlloader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Parent root = fxmlloader.getRoot();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Space Invaders ohne Anmeldung");

        PlayAnonymController controller = fxmlloader.getController();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(controller::movePlayer);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: start() method is delete. In my 'movePlayer(KeyEvent event)' If I use arrow key LEFT or RIGHT, the rectangle moves. But I can't press LEFT or RIGHT multiple times. The rectangle only moves once. What can I do? @James_D

Comment: @Shorn That sounds like a different, albeit related, question. The new code in your question sets the translation to the same value every time it’s invoked. So pressing the key the second time will move it to the same place it was moved when you pressed the key the first time. I think I have answered your original question here. You have a new question. However, if I’m honest, the new question is really not worth posting here. You cannot expect to rely on StackOverflow for every tiny piece of logic. At some point you should simply try thinking.